# Excel VBA getting contents of merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sheet.

[image]

In VBA I get the contents of row 8 column AV, AU, AW, like this.

```
.Cells(row_level - 1, col_comment)
```

Row 7 is a merged cell.  I would like to get the contents of AV if the column is AV, AU, or AW.  The tricky part is that there aren't always three merged columns.  There might be anywhere from 2 to 7.

Comment: If `.Cells(r, c)` refers to any cell in a merged range, `.Cells(r, c).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value` will return the merged areas value

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer

    Set rngDB = Range("au8", Range("au" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng.MergeCells Then
            If rng.Address = rng.MergeArea.Range("a1").Address Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To n)
                For j = 1 To 3
                    vR(j, n) = rng(1, j)
                Next j
            End If
        Else
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To 3
                vR(j, n) = rng(1, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next rng
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```